# Java how to Convert String Date format

Tags: java, date, date-format

How to Convert String date format example I have Date like this

`2019-01-01`

and change the format into

`2019-01`

the year and date only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Is that your only requirement? If yes, cut the last three characters? No, seriously, have a look at `java.time`, especially `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` and `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Did you mean "year and month" in that last line? "year and date" (as in day-of-month) makes no sense.

Comment: What does this have to do with databases and SQLite? Delete extraneous tags.

Comment: So `2019-09-29` should become `2019-29`? For what purpose if I may be curious? Or did you mean that the day of the year should come after the hyphen, so `2019-272`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) like this :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM");
String result = formatter.format(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01"));
```

The **result** should be

```
2019-01
```

---

**About parsing**

you can use `LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01")` because parse use by default `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`, which is the same format of your **String**

---

```
public static LocalDate parse(CharSequence text) {
    return parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth
.from(
    LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-01" )
)
.toString()
```

> 2019-01

## `YearMonth`

I suppose you meant "year and month" in that last line. If so, use the `YearMonth` class, along with `LocalDate`.

First, parse the `LocalDate` as shown in [correct Answer by guest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54780834/642706).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-01" ) ;
```

Extract a `YearMonth` object to represent, well, the year and the month.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld ) ;
```

Generate text representing this value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = ym.toString() ;
```

> 2019-01